# How do I request and receive user input in a .bat and use it to run a certain program?

Tags: input, batch-file

This is what I have so far

```
@echo off
:Ask
echo Would you like to use developer mode?(Y/N)
set INPUT=
set /P INPUT=Type input: %=%
If %INPUT%=="y" goto yes 
If %INPUT%=="n" goto no
If %INPUT%=="Y" goto yes
If %INPUT%=="N" goto no
:yes
java -jar lib/RSBot-4030.jar -dev
echo Starting RSbot in developer mode
:no
java -jar lib/RSBot-4030.jar
echo Starting RSbot in regular mode
pause
```

Either way if the user enters y or n it always runs in -dev mode.

How do I make it run in -dev mode if the answer is yes, and regular mode if the answer is no. Also, how do I make it ask again if the input isn't Y, N, y, or n?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If the input is, say, `N`, your IF lines evaluate like this:

```
If N=="y" goto yes 
If N=="n" goto no
…
```

That is, you are comparing `N` with `"y"`, then `"n"` etc. including `"N"`. You are never going to get a match unless the user somehow decides to input `"N"` or `"y"` (i.e. either of the four characters, but enclosed in double quotes).

So you need either to remove `"` from around `y`, `n`, `Y` and `N` or put them around `%INPUT%` in your conditional statements. I would recommend the latter, because that way you would be escaping at least some of the characters that have special meaning in batch scripts (if the user managed to type them in). So, this is what you should get:

```
If "%INPUT%"=="y" goto yes 
If "%INPUT%"=="n" goto no
If "%INPUT%"=="Y" goto yes
If "%INPUT%"=="N" goto no
```

By the way, you could reduce the number of conditions by applying the `/I` switch to the `IF` statement, like this:

```
If /I "%INPUT%"=="y" goto yes 
If /I "%INPUT%"=="n" goto no
```

The `/I` switch makes the comparisons case-insensitive, and so you don't need separate checks for different-case strings.

One other issue is that, after the development mode command is executed, there's no jumping over the other command, and so, if the user agrees to run Java in the development mode, he'll get it run both in the development mode and the non-development mode. So maybe you need to add something like this to your script:

```
...
:yes
java -jar lib/RSBot-4030.jar -dev
echo Starting RSbot in developer mode
goto cont
:no
java -jar lib/RSBot-4030.jar
echo Starting RSbot in regular mode
:cont
pause
```

Finally, to address the issue of processing incorrect input, you could simply add another (unconditional) `goto` command just after the conditional statements, just before the `yes` label, namely `goto Ask`, to return to the beginning of your script where the prompt is displayed and the input is requested, or you could *also* add another ECHO command before the jump, explaining that the input was incorrect, something like this:

```
@echo off
:Ask
echo Would you like to use developer mode?(Y/N)
set INPUT=
set /P INPUT=Type input: %=%
If /I "%INPUT%"=="y" goto yes 
If /I "%INPUT%"=="n" goto no
echo Incorrect input & goto Ask
:yes
...
```

---

*Note: Some of the issues mentioned here have also been addressed by @xmjx in their answer, which I fully acknowledge.*

Answer (score 7):

i just do :

```
set /p input= yes or no
if %input%==yes echo you clicked yes
if %input%==no echo you clicked no
pause
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a working example:

```
@echo off
:ask
@echo echo Would you like to use developer mode?(Y/N)
set INPUT=
set /P INPUT=Type input: %=%
If /I "%INPUT%"=="y" goto yes 
If /I "%INPUT%"=="n" goto no
goto ask
:yes
@echo you select yes
goto exit
:no
@echo you select no
goto exit
:exit
@pause
```

Comment: Why did you add the @ before pause?

Answer (score 1):

I have improved batch file with yes or no prompt. If user enter any character except y and n , then it will again prompt user for valid input.  It Works for me.

```
    @echo off

    :ConfirmBox 
        set /P c= Are you sure want to contine (y/n)?

    if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" (
    goto :FnYes 
    ) else if /I "%c%" EQU "N" ( 
    goto :FnNo
    ) else ( 
    goto :InValid 
    )


:FnYes
     echo You have entered Y
     goto :END

:FnNo
     echo You have entered N
     goto :END

:InValid
     echo Invalid selection. Enter Y or N
     goto :ConfirmBox

:END
    pause
    exit
```

/I in if condition will validate both lowercase and uppercase characters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the platform you're doing this on but I assume Windows due to the .bat extension.

Also I don't have a way to check this but this seems like the batch processor skips the If lines due to some errors and then executes the one with -dev.

You could try this by chaning the two jump targets (`:yes` and `:no`) along with the code. If then the line without -dev is executed you know your If lines are erroneous.

If so, please check if `==` is really the right way to do a comparison in `.bat` files.

Also, judging from the way bash does this stuff, `%foo=="y"` might evaluate to true only if `%foo` includes the quotes. So maybe `"%foo"=="y"` is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks it worked, but how would I make it so that if none of those if statements are true, it goes back to ask.

Comment: You already have the :Ask label. So just add a goto Ask right after the fourth If line.

Comment: Oh, I guess for following readers it might be interesting which solution actually helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo off
setlocal
SET AREYOUSURE = N
:PROMPT
set /P AREYOUSURE=Update Release Files (Y/N)?
if /I %AREYOUSURE% NEQ Y GOTO END
set /P AREYOUSURE=Are You Sure you want to Update Release Files (Y/N)?
if /I %AREYOUSURE% NEQ Y GOTO END

echo Copying New Files

:END
```

This is code I use regularly. I have noticed in the examples in this blog that quotes are used. If the test line is changed to use quotes the test is invalid.

```
if /I %AREYOUSURE% NEQ "Y" GOTO END
```

I have tested on XP, Vista, Win7 and Win8. All fail when quotes are used.

Comment: Try putting quotation marks on both strings like this: `if /I "%AREYOUSURE%" NEQ "Y" GOTO END`

Comment: See this answser for better approach using `choice`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13915595/207661

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of Windows you might find the use of the "Choice" option to be helpful.  It is not supported in most if not all x64 versions as far as I can tell.
A handy substitution called Choice.vbs along with examples of use can be found on SourceForge under the name Choice.zip

Comment: Please provide the code for it.Instead of user searching through net for it.

Answer (score -2):

Add quotation marks (" ") around the %INPUT% so it looks like this:

```
If "%INPUT%" == "y" goto yes
If "%INPUT%" == "n" goto no
If "%INPUT%" == "Y" goto yes
If "%INPUT%" == "N" goto no
```

Comment: The one year old answer of Andriy M addressed exactly this, but also with a good explanation

Answer (score -3):

try this for comparision

```
if "%INPUT%"=="y"...
```

Comment: The one year old answer of Andriy M addressed exactly this, but also with a good explanation