# yes/no batch file

Tags: batch-file

In my batch file I want to ask the user a question.

I wrote the following:

```
SET /P ANSWER=Click Y to continue or N to stop (Y/N)
```

but I get the message without the last `)`.

Someone know why?

Thanks!

Comment: It works fine for me. Does it give you an error? Or does it just not display the last bracket?

Comment: not display the last bracket

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because you're using that prompt within a parenthesised block, e.g.

```
if ... (
  ...
  set /P ANSWER=Blah (Y/N)
)
```

or

```
for %%x in (...) do (
  ...
  set /P ANSWER=Blah (Y/N)
)
```

You have to escape the closing parenthesis in that case:

```
SET /P ANSWER=Click Y to continue or N to stop (Y/N^)
```

or quote the whole argument:

```
SET /P "ANSWER=Click Y to continue or N to stop (Y/N)"
```

otherwise it closes the block. And if you had anything after that closing parenthesis you'd get a syntax error.

An easier method of what you do there would probably be the `choice` command:

```
choice /M "Press Y to continue or N to stop" /c YN
```

You can then check the errorlevel afterwards to find out the user's choice:

```
if errorlevel 255 (
  echo Error
) else if errorlevel 2 (
  echo No.
) else if errorlevel 1 (
  echo Yes.
) else if errorlevel 0 (
  echo Ctrl+C pressed.
)
```

Comment: (Y/N^) - dont help to the problem and choice command cause to my batch to failed

Comment: +1 - Even easier I think is to use quotes: `set /p "answer=Click Y to continue (Y/N)". I'm pretty sure CHOICE is not standard on some Windows versions.