# Batch Yes/No option

Tags: batch-file

I'm busy to build a script for myself which empties different folders but I want make a Yes / No choise for the user where N goes back to the menu and Y runs the script.

This is what I got:

```
:temp

CHOICE /C YN /M "Enter your choice:" 
IF ERRORLEVEL Y GOTO deltemp
IF ERRORLEVEL N goto reset

:reset
goto menu

:deltemp
```

Now it goes direct to the menu, I think in cause of the :reset what is above :deltemp.

Comment: The last code block of this answer is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12021798/4363604

Answer (score 4, accepted):

errorlevel can have only numeric values.CHOICE command sets increments errorlevel for every next letter:

```
:temp

CHOICE /C YN /M "Enter your choice:" 
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 goto reset
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO deltemp


:reset
goto menu

:deltemp
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if I'm correct Y is 1 and 2 is N?

Comment: @npocmaka had no coffee yet ;). I corrected his answer. Please try again

Comment: You're both awesome, it works! Now only need to know how to delete everything in temp but that seems a new question?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915536/yes-no-batch-file