# batch script to download a file via ftp, how can I handle the overwrite

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

Good day all.
I've done a batch script that connects to an FTP and download a file on the same location of the .bat file. everything works fine, now, is there a way to "ask for file overwrite permissions"? I mean, if the user already have a file named in the same way, is it possible to prevent overwrite and ask him what to do? the code actually is :

```
@echo off
echo user MYUSERNAME> ftpcmd.dat
echo MYPASSWORD>> ftpcmd.dat
echo bin>> ftpcmd.dat
echo cd /www.website.com/>>ftpcmd.dat
echo get afile.txt>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat ftp.website.com
del ftpcmd.dat
```

Comment: Use `if exist "afile.txt"` in your batch script before the `ftp` command line? then you could conditionally prompt the user for Yes or No to overwrite using `choice`...

Comment: oh, that's good, I'll research a bit more on this, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `if exist "afile.txt"` in advance and use `choice` to let the user decide what to do:

```
@echo off
if exist "afile.txt" (
    choice /C YN /M "Overwrite 'afile.txt'? "
) else (
    > nul ver & rem (clear `Errorlevel`)
)
if not ErrorLevel 2 (
    > "ftpcmd.dat" (
        echo user MYUSERNAME
        echo MYPASSWORD
        echo bin
        echo cd /www.website.com/
        echo get afile.txt
        echo quit
    )
    ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat ftp.website.com
    del "ftpcmd.dat"
)
```

<strike>However, since there is no `-i` switch in the `ftp` command line and the interactive `prompt` mode should be on as per default, I assume the `ftp` command would prompt the user anyway...</strike>
Corrective Update: *The "interactive mode" means that the `mget` and `mput` will ask user to confirm transfer of each matching file, not matter if it exists or not. See [technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490670.aspx](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490670.aspx). There are no overwrite confirmations in `ftp.exe`.* [[Martin Prikryl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850848/martin-prikryl)]

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`if exist` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/if) to test, if the local file exists already before the transfer.

If it exists, [ask an user for confirmation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12021033/850848).

```
@echo off

if not exist afile.txt goto download

:ask
echo Overwrite?
set INPUT=
set /P INPUT=Y/N: %=%
If /I "%INPUT%"=="Y" goto download
If /I "%INPUT%"=="N" exit
echo Incorrect input
goto ask

:download
...
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat ftp.website.com
```

---

*Though for a long term solution, you better use PowerShell, instead of hacking this in a batch file.*